# Can a projectile entity be anonymized?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

There is a feature in minecraft, that an arrow will break item frames. However, on SMP server users can protect their regions and the region is smart enough to check the origin ID of the arrow. Still, I wonder if anyone could mess up with our spawn's crafting tutorials (which are made of item frames).

One way would be leading a skeleton archer to the spawn, but I guess that would require inhuman patience. Also, dispenser arrows seem to be anonymous, but in my case that's something  don't have to worry about.

Comment: Why not just spawn a skeleton at spawn to test it (assuming you are OP)?

Comment: I'm talking about player projectiles. Skeleton projectiles are skeleton projectiles - and at the time of this question they could break even the protected frames.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to disallow breaking of the item frames you can always give them resistance 4, rendering them invincible. Or setup a plugin to disallow mobs into spawn, making it impossible for a skeleton to shoot at the frames.

Comment: No, I was, on the contrary, asking how to bypass the protection.